# how can I use data in function at the parent component in a child component in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new in react and nextjs
i want use "reponse" (in function in the parent component) in the other component(component1 ).

```
function func1(props) {
    
    
    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(e.target);
        const form_values = Object.fromEntries(formData);
        axios.get(`here is my url`,{
            params : form_values,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET',
              },
        }).then(function (**response**) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
        
      }


    return ( 
        <component1 data={**response**} />

    )

export default func1;
```

i have no idea what's the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by storing the data in [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). When the axios completes, update the state variable. Pass this state down to the component as a prop.

For example, if your data is an array then this would work:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function func1(props) {
    
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    
    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(e.target);
        const form_values = Object.fromEntries(formData);
        axios.get(`here is my url`,{
            params : form_values,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET',
              },
        }).then(function (response) {
            setData(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
        
      }


    return ( 
        <component1 data={data} />

    )

export default func1;
```

Depending in what you do in `component1`, you may need to check if the data is an empty array before using it.

Side note: setting headers `Access-Control-Allow-*` like that are setting them as `request` headers and will do nothing to bypass CORS. These headers must be set by the server in the response.